# How does Http live streaming works?

Tags: live-streaming, http-live-streaming, http-streaming

I have created one sample application for demonstrating a working of HTTP live streaming.
What I have done is, I have one library that takes input as video file (avi, mpeg, mov, .ts) and generating segments (.ts) and playlist (.m3u8) files for the given video file.   I am storing playlist (as string) in a linked list, as an when i am getting playlist data from the library.

I have written one basic web server which will server the user requested segment and playlist files. I am requesting playlist.m3u8 file from the iPhone safari browser and it is launching the QuickTime player where it is requesting the segment.ts files listed in the received playlist files.  after playing every segments (listed in current playlist) it again requests for the playlist, where i am responding with the next playlist file which contains the next set of segment.ts files listed in it.

Is this what we call HTTP live streaming?
Is there anything else, other that this i need to do for implementing HTTP live streaming?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Not much more. If you are taking input streams of media, encoding them, encapsulating in a format suitable for delivery and preparing the encapsulated media for distribution by placing it in such a way that they can be requested from the HTTP server, you are done. The idea behind the live streaming is that it leverages existing Internet architecture that is already optimized for serving HTTP requests for reasonably sized resources.

HTTP streaming renders many existing CDN solutions obsolete with their custom streaming protocols, custom routing and custom content caching.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use media stream validator command line application for mac os x for validating streams generated by the HTTP Web server.

Answer (score 0):

More or less but there's also adaptive bit-rate streaming to take care of if you want your server to push files to iOS devices. Which means your scope expands from having a single "index.m3u8" file that tracks all the TS files to a master index that then tracks the index files for each bitrate you'd want to support in your application which then individually track the TS files encoded at the respective bit-rates.

It's a good amount of work, but mostly routine/repetitive once you've got the hang of the basics.

For more on streaming, your bible, from the iOS standpoint, should ALWAYS be [TN2224](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#technotes/tn2224/_index.html). Adhering closely to the specs in the Technote, is your best chance of getting through the App Store approval process vis-a-vis streaming.

Some people don't bother (building a streaming app over the past couple of months and looked at the HTTP logs of a whole bunch of video apps that don't quite seem to stick by the rules) - sometimes Apple notices, sometimes they don't, and sometimes the player is just too big for Apple to interfere.

So it's not very different there from every other aspect of the functionality of your app that undergoes Apple's scrutiny. It's just that there are ways you can be sure you're on the right track.

And of course, from a purely technical standpoint, as @psp1 mentioned the mediastreamvalidator tool can help you figure out if your streams are - at their very core, even if not in terms of their overall abilities - compatible with what's expected of HLS implementations.

**Note:** You can either roll with your own encoding solution (with ffmpeg, the plus being you have more control, the minus being it takes time to configure and get working just RIGHT. Plus once you start talking even the least amount of scale, you run into a whole host of other problems. And once you're done with all the technical hard-work, you'd find that was easy. Now you'd have to actually figure out which license you need to get for having a fancy H.264 encoder with you and jump through all the legal/procedural hoops to get one).

The easier solution for a developer without a legal/accounting team that could fill a football field, IMO, it's easier to go third-party with sites like Encoding.com, Zencoder etc who provide their encoding services a-la-carte or with a monthly fee. The plus is that they've taken care of all the licensing BS and are just providing you a simple "pay to use" service, which could also be extremely useful when you're building a project for a client. The minus is that you're now DEPENDENT on Zencoder/Encoding, the flip-side of which you'd know when your encoding jobs fail for a whole day because their servers are down, or even otherwise, when the API doesn't quite act as you expect or has been documented!

But anyhow that's about all the factors you got to Grok before pushing a HLS server into production!